# convert list<string> to list<decimal> using TryParse C#

Tags: c#

If possible, How can we convert List of string to list of decimal using `decimal.TryParse` whose return type is `bool` so that I can do something like this

```
if(true)
{
//to do
} 
else
{
// to do
}
```

Comment: What should happen when the string *cannot* be successfully converted? A loop of some kind is needed, but LINQ generally makes this an easy task. The posted code is also a bit .. confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily convert your `list<string>` to array `listItem[]` by

```
listItem[] strArr = yourList.ToArray();
```

Now, define some `decimal array` and try to convert them using `TryParse` as

```
decimal n;
decimal[] decArr;
if(strArr.All(x => Decimal.TryParse(x, out n)))
{
 decArr = Array.ConvertAll<string,decimal>(strArr, Convert.ToDecimal);
}
else
{
//to do
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that I'm selecting only the values that converted successfully:

```
List<string> lstStr = GetListString(); // Get it somehow

List<decimal> decs = lstStr.Select(str =>
{
   decimal item = 0m;
   return new 
   {
     IsParsed =  decimal.TryParse(str, out item),
     Value = item
   };
}).Where(o => o.IsParsed).Select(o => o.Value).ToList();
```